# How to get all available Sounds file listed in system settings in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio

I would like to show a picker view or list of all available phone sounds. So that way user can change sound alert for app(It will not effect in system sound file).

One of app feature will allow user to play selected sound within app only.

Please let me know if there any way to perform this.

Thanks! Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use System Sound Services to play short (30 seconds or
   shorter) sounds. The interface does not provide level, positioning,
   looping, or timing control, and does not support simultaneous
   playback: You can play only one sound at a time.
       Link for apple system sound services 
           https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/system_sound_services

   ```
       // import this
       import AVFoundation

       // create a sound ID, in this case its the tweet sound.
       let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016

       // to play sound
       AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
   ```

Comment: Small project demonstrating of how to locate and use system sound files https://github.com/CQH/iOS-Sounds-and-Ringtones